using a preshader before the p5.js phongshader
I'd like to be able to modify the vertex positions in a vertex shader BEFORE using phongmaterial.
I can think of two solutions:

apply a shader that modifies the coordinates before the phongShader passes over them
download a version of phongShader compatible with p5.js and modify it. But I don't find it.


I  found a solution
Here a video to how to build shaders : Introduction to Phong Lighting
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKXAIuCaKAQ

End the code of this shader :
https://github.com/SuboptimalEng/shader-tutorials/blob/1b81e335354d1f312023a6bc95a27b21a7919841/01-phong-lighting/shader.frag
